# Function overloading for class methods is a compiler error despite the documentation

Tags: node.js, typescript

According to [this documentation](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/function-overloading), TypeScript should allow you to overload functions, but when I try to do that in the context of class methods, it results in a compiler error. What am I doing wrong?

```
// This approach does NOT work
class Sanitizer {
    sanitizeDate(date: string): string { // COMPILER ERROR: "Duplicate function implementation"
        return date.replace(/\//g, '-');
    }

    sanitizeDate(date: Date): string { // COMPILER ERROR: "Duplicate function implementation"
        return `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getDate()}`;
    }
}

const sanitizer = new Sanitizer();

const pathFriendlyDate1 = sanitizer.sanitizeDate('2019/08/08');
const now = new Date();
const pathFriendlyDate2 = sanitizer.sanitizeDate(now); // COMPILER ERROR: "Argument of type 'Date' not assignable to parameter of type 'string'"

// ----------------------------------------
// This approach DOES work (no overloading)
class SanitizerNoOverloading {
    sanitizeDateStr(date: string): string {
        return date.replace(/\//g, '-');
    }

    sanitizeDate(date: Date): string {
        return `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getDate()}`;
    }
}

const sanitizer2 = new SanitizerNoOverloading();

const pathFriendlyDate3 = sanitizer2.sanitizeDateStr('2019/08/08');
const pathFriendlyDate4 = sanitizer2.sanitizeDate(now);
```

I get the 2 compiler errors saying "Duplicate function implementation".

Is there a tsc setting I need to change to get this to work, or is it just not supported?

Comment: The linked website is not a very clear description. The official documentation is more accurate https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way overloading works in typescript is just signature overloading. You can have multiple signatures for the same method (with a private implementation signature that satisfies all overloads) but a single method body. It is up to the implementation to distinguish between overloads. You can read more about this in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).

```
class Sanitizer {
    sanitizeDate(date: Date): string
    sanitizeDate(date: string): string
    sanitizeDate(date: Date | string): string {
        if (typeof date === "string") {
            return date.replace(/\//g, '-');
        } else {
            return `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getDate()}`;
        }
    }
}

var s = new Sanitizer();
s.sanitizeDate("a")
s.sanitizeDate(new Date());
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKYDsCWAXJAvApgJ2gbwChpjoJFUNMARMFTACgBNbMAuaGugSnYhWyQIA5kRJlkaLJwbM6vfoKE9SC4aOLiKUlkxbtp0AD4qBw5X1ND86ksSQAzaPRQBPAA6YA9o9mZoAXkDoACILRWCua1tokmxMFABXbARoXwA6OLdwYAYAegAdXNyhABpoAHIAWnKuAG4bWwBfaEwQCD9CGJi4xOToAAMAEjx0oXiAMQSQEABNTDBsei5GyuHR+IBZTwQUAAsl6ABqaABGFbWWNLGUaSXG-vqu6EabF5eCADcF0gDoBEwAO5wciSHBLeoQNKaUG3YJgCIESHQyi3f5A25cOoEIA)

The reason for this approach is that JavaScript does not have true function overloading, and the goal of typescript is just to add types to JavaScript not to add any extra  runtime features to the language.